# Can I use Grails Ehcache Cache Plugin with ehcache.xml?

Tags: caching, grails, plugins, ehcache

I need `ehcache.xml` file to configure custom settings (like Ehcache Monitor). Is it possible to use `ehcache.xml` file with `*Cache.groovy`? How can I configure custom settings that is not described in [cache dsl](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html#dsl)